# Extract a value from a dictionary column type of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My current data frame looks like this:

```
      ID       Date            Data
00112   11-02-2014        {'address1': '161 Glensford Dr', 'address2': '', 'address3': '', 'city': 'Fayetteville', 'zip_code': '28314', 'country': 'US', 'state': 'NC', 'display_address': ['161 Glensford Dr', 'Fayetteville, NC 28314'], 'cross_streets': ''}
00112   11-02-2014       {...}
00112   30-07-2015       {...}
00112   30-07-2015       {...}
```

I would like to access to the column Data and get the value for all my rows of "address1"
I have the same format for all my rows for this Data column:

```
{'address1': '1909 Skibo Rd', 'address2': '', 'address3': '', 'city': 'Fayetteville', 'zip_code': '28314', 'country': 'US', 'state': 'NC', 'display_address': ['1909 Skibo Rd', 'Fayetteville, NC 28314'], 'cross_streets': ''}
```

I do not how to get the value of address1 for each row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711059/extract-dictionary-value-from-column-in-data-frame Look at it. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looping through the rows of the `Data` column:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
```

Then get the data from dictionary using the standard dictionary `get` function:

```
print(idx, row['Data'].get("address1"))
```

So it's just 2 lines:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(idx, row['Data'].get("address1"))
```

Edit: if you already have a series assigned to the correct column:

```
series = df["Data"]
for idx, each in series.iteritems():
    print(idx, each.get("address1"))
```

Comment: I got this AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Comment: I used `df` to refer to your entire dataframe, not a series within the dataframe. If you already have a series variable then you should use `iteritems` like this: `for idx, each in <your_series_variable>.iteritems():`. Also replace `row['Data']` with `each`

Comment: I have edited the answer to include this

Comment: Thank you, I am still having this AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: I change my column to string df['Data'] = df['Data'].astype(str)

Comment: Strings don't have a `get` function, only dictionaries do. So there is no reason for you to use `.astype(str)`. Remove that and it should work.

Comment: Yes, but is not working. I am only importing my csv. My column data is type 'Object' this is an example for one row `{'address1': '161 Glensford Dr', 'address2': '', 'address3': '', 'city': 'Fayetteville', 'zip_code': '28314', 'country': 'US', 'state': 'NC', 'display_address': ['161 Glensford Dr', 'Fayetteville, NC 28314'], 'cross_streets': ''}`I do not why this is not working :(

Comment: Since you haven't provided code I can't tell. Take a look at the example I reproduced here: online-python.com/OaS9HfPbqG and try to match your code to this.